# Grails domain removeFrom is trying to remove based on Index instead of object

Tags: string, grails, indexing, grails-domain-class

I am not sure whether this is a bug or my misunderstanding. Kindly help me out. If it's a bug i can raise a jira ticket with Grails.

My domain class looks like below.

```
class MyDomainClass {
   List ids

   static hasMany = [ids:Integer]
}
```

When i do the following its works just fine.

```
def my = MyDomainClass.get(1)
my.addToIds(2)
my.save(flush:true)
```

Now here is the problem. If i try removing the 2 from ids i am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
my.removeFromIds(2) //This is trying to get the index instead of the value.
(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1)
```

This works if i have the property as `"static hasMany = [ids:String]"` in my domain object. But everytime i have to use .toString and .toInteger which i don't want to.

I believe there is no removeFrom{property}(index) method and there is only removeFrom{property}(Object)

Grails version : 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Without going to much in details, I'd wrap the `Integer id` into a new domain class like

```
class MyId {

  MyId( id ){ this.id = id }

  static belongsTo = MyDomainClass

}
```

and use `hasMany` in a proper way:

```
class MyDomainClass {

  static hasMany = [ids:MyId]
}
```

then

```
def my = MyDomainClass.get(1)
my.addToIds new MyId( 2 )
my.save(flush:true)
my.removeFromIds( MyId.get( 2 ) )
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new domain class just to wrap the id, i used Long and its working as expected. I believe removeFrom method with argument as Integer is there for a reason(To maintain the order of the list). So the modified code will look like this.

```
class MyDomainClass {
   List ids
   static hasMany = [ids:Long]
}
```